# Can't install libmodman from source

Tags: 11.10, bash

I have this file *libmodman-2.0.1.tar.gz*, and want to install it, so I extracted it, navigated to the directory, then `./ configure` and I get this :

> ~/Downloads/libmodman-2.0.1$ ./configure
>   bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

This is the content of the *libmodman-2.0.1* directory:

```
/cmake/
/libmodman/
AUTHORS
CMakeLists.txt
COPYING
INSTALL
NEWS
```

In the file install is this:

```
cmake ./
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I tried `cmake ./` in the terminal but i get this :

> bash: ./cmake: Is a directory

How can I install this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be trying to run cmake in ~/Downloads/libmodman-2.0.1/

Then once you have done that as the INSTALL file says, run `make`, `make test` and then `sudo make install`.

So that is:

```
cd ~/Downloads/libmodman-2.0.1/
cmake ./
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Comment: I thought I was doing that, i thought I was running cmake ./ in ~/Downloads/libmodman-2.0.1/ the first time, but obviously not, cause today it worked as you said. Thank you very much !